# SQL 3 tables join

Tags: sql, mariadb

Imagine that I have 3 tables(role, user and user_has_role), the
common column between the 3 tables is the id. the question is that
every username can have multiple roles and I want to join them
together regarding to id but when a username has more than 1 row, I
want these all roles on the same row separated with commas and not
having for example 2 rows with same id, same user name but different
roles, No I want in a row a single id, a single username and
multiple roles

The Tables I have:

```
User:

    id    username                              
    1     jack                           
    3     john

Role:

    id    role                          
    1     23 
    2     22                            
    3     33                            
    3     35 


user_has_role:

    user_id  role_id
    1        1
    1        2
    2        3
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
    id    username    roles
    1     jack        23,22
    2     john        33
```

Comment: So, what have you tried?  Do you have some SQL you can add for us to examine?  What problem are you having?

Comment: @Russ i tried this 

SELECT u.id as uid, username

, role

 

FROM user u

INNER JOIN

user_has_role uhr

ON

u.id = uhr.user_id

 

INNER JOIN

role r

ON

r.id = uhr.role_id

ORDER BY 2

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: if you tag your question with the database that you are using, we can provide a better answer (because of the FOR XML feature)

Comment: I believe that i can't do that because it's a huge database and can't be uploaded, but i will say that (one person can have more than one role, how am I able to gather the whole roles in a single cell, without repeating the whole row?)
that means i want the id, the username and the whole roles all in one row.
Thank you

Comment: I'm using MariaDB
@a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `group_concat` as follows:

```
select u.id as user_id,
       u.username,
       group_concat(r.role_id ORDER BY r.role_id SEPARATOR ',') as roles
  from user u join user_has_role r on r.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.username
```

Comment: it works but still one last thing, in the table role I have role and id (it's the role id) I want the role as a name to show instead of its id

Comment: group_concat(r.role_name ORDER BY r.role_name SEPARATOR ',') as roles

Comment: here is the problem I tried that before it didn't work, the column in the role table called also "role" and didnt work with role_name @popeye